# Datorama array size after the use of SPLIT

Tags: object, array, field-mapping, datorama

On Datorama when trying to get the length of an array I'm able to get it using a calculated dimension by:

```
 a = SPLIT([Media_Buy_Name],'_')
 return EXTRACT(a[a.length-1],'&',0)
```

But when using the formula editor inside the mapping tool, the same code is not working : *class not found: java.lang.Object$length*

Comment: What if there's only one element in the array -- `a`?  Even if it's not syntactically correct, it would be problematic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this, where `str` is `[Media_Buy_Name]`:

```java
str = 'this_is_a_test_whee&whoa&whoop';
arr = SPLIT(str,'_');
b = arr.length;
if (b > 0) {  
  return EXTRACT(arr[b-1],"&",0)
} else {
  return str
}
```

I validated this in Datorama and it returned:

```
whee
```

**Update**

According to one of my astute co-workers, your original expression was missing a semicolon.  This'll return the same results as my expression above.

```
a = SPLIT('this_is_a_test_whee&whoa&whoop','_');
return EXTRACT(a[a.length-1],'&',0)
```

Comment: Thanks to the co-worker :D